# SMTP(500 Access Denied) Error but i can send mail to gmail or hotmail

Tags: linux, email, smtp, centos, exim

I can successfully send email to Gmail or Hotmail accounts but cannot send email like mail@specialdomain.com mail adresses. I use exim on CentOs server. When i send the email I get this error:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<my@mail.com> SIZE=5598:
 host example.com [XX.XXX.X.63]: 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
```

I use 587 port for smtp. What should I change on my server or my mail configuration?

Comment: Do you really have a `example.com` string in your log?

Comment: it is a bit unclear from your question, are you failing to send FROM mail@specialdomain.com or TO mail@specialdomain.com?

Comment: All e-mails and domains are symbolic in my question. I send mail to example.com domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Receiving servers will be more or less strict about HELO string (and other sending server's setting) - the main purpose being spam fighting. Some measures could include:

- Reject connections where the domain provided at HELO and EHLO has
  neither an 'A' nor an 'MX' record in DNS
- Reject the request when the HELO or EHLO hostname is not in fully-qualified domain or address literal form, as required by the RFC
- Check if hosts have a valid RDNS matching the EHLO
- Check hostname against list of regexes that matches various names dynamically assigned by ISP like xxxx.dynamic.yyy.com or 12-34-56-78.dsl.zzz.com

With that in mind, your server is most probably misconfigured. The error message is pretty precise: HELO name that your server presents is not compliant with RFC2821 so receiving server won't accept an email.
First check your server hostname and after that check EXIM configuration (probably `/etc/exim/exim.conf`) and see if primary_hostname or helo_data value are configured.

Comment: Thanks ! I checked exim.conf file and comment in `helo_data = $sender_address_domain` line.